# Hide Microsoft Word Shape Border While Printing

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I need some help regarding the Shapes Layout in Word Format. I have a word template that has some shapes in it, I want the result when the user tries to print the file or save it in PDF, it should not include the shape borders in it.

My Word File: [Download Here](https://www.aalabels.com/theme/site/images/office/word/AAS008.doc?v=1615205787)

Desired File: [Download Here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/avery.dpp.projects.s3uspdownloadables/US_en/Downloadables/doc/U-0090-01.doc?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DAvery5163ShippingLabels.doc&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJVLHRSWM7XNZAFYQ&Expires=1615812475&Signature=%2F0BvoRv5IkXuZZSjcxolajZJGUQ%3D)

[Actual File - While Editing The Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhXxS.png)

[While Printing CTRL+P (Desired Result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alE6w.png)

I have found a script online that removes the shapes completely, I only want to remove the borders and retain the text/images inside the shape.
The script is as follows:

```
Sub PrintNoImagesOrShapesInDoc()
Dim objDoc As Document
Dim objInLineShape As InlineShape
Dim objShape As Shape

'  Initialization
Set objDoc = ActiveDocument

'  Find all images and shapes in the active document and then hide them to prevent from being 
printed.
With objDoc
  For Each objInLineShape In .InlineShapes
  objInLineShape.Select
  Selection.Font.Hidden = False
Next objInLineShape
   Options.PrintDrawingObjects = False
End With

Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint).Show

With objDoc
For Each objInLineShape In .InlineShapes
  objInLineShape.Select
  Selection.Font.Hidden = False
Next objInLineShape
End With
End Sub
```

Any Positive Help will be appreciated

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For example, to save as a PDF:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim objUndo As UndoRecord, Shp As Shape
Set objUndo = Application.UndoRecord
With ActiveDocument
  objUndo.StartCustomRecord ("RecordName")
  For Each Shp In .Shapes
    Shp.Line.Visible = False
  Next
  .SaveAs FileName:=Split(.FullName, ".doc")(0) & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
  objUndo.EndCustomRecord
  .Undo
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```